# how to regex a string+digit pattern in mysql

Tags: mysql, regex

I have this pattern in urls and I need to extract the 4 digit numbers out of the url. The patter looks like this:

```
hotel1234 
/1234.html
```

I tried

```
  select sdate,url,
  case when url like '/%.html' then substring_index(url,'.',1)
  when url REGEXP 'HOTEL'+'[0-9].{4}' then left(substring_index(url,'HOTEL',-1),4)          
        else url
        end digit
  from urltable
```

This does not work on some of the url.
i would like to regexp on '/1234.html',what is the right expression?

Comment: `+` is for math. Why not put it all in the quotes? `.{4}` is 4 any characters.

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work:

```
SELECT url, 
CASE WHEN url LIKE '/%.html' THEN SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(url,'.',1), 2)
  WHEN url REGEXP '[a-zA-Z]{5}[0-9]{4}' THEN substring(url, -4)         
        ELSE url
        END digit
FROM test;
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e33be5/6/0)**.